# Program in rc.local started not with standard localization

Tags: autostart, localization

I have experienced that when I start my program during the start process with rc.local the format of the date does not correspond to the standard localization setting.
When I execute the same program / the rc.local file manually I get the right format.
Is there anything I can do about this problem?

That is what I get when I execute locale manually:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

that when it is executed by rc.local

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Post the output of `locale` when you run it manually, and when you use it in `rc.local` (maybe add `locale > /tmp/rc-locale` to it).

Comment: Added the information to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have your command use a given locale's time format, just set the `LC_TIME` variable for it. For example, if your command in `rc.local` is:

```
/path/to/foo arg1 arg2 ...
```

Use:

```
/usr/bin/env LC_TIME=de_AT.UTF-8 /path/to/foo arg1 arg2 ...
```

You can also set additional locale variables this way, but for the time format, `LC_TIME` should be enough.